# Installshield 2016 failed to verify digital signature of

Tags: window, installshield

I recently upgraded a 2012 installshield project to 2016, when building the upgraded project, i got the error as below

ISDEV : fatal error -7210: Failed to verify digital signature of C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2016\system\IsUiServices.dll
Error -2147467259: Automation error
Unspecified error

Please advise the root cause and a solution.
Thanks

Comment: This can occur when your machine's root certificates are out of date. They are typically updated by Windows Update. Is the machine fully updated?

Answer (score 0):

Theres a .CER certificate for InstallShield, and it need to be put on "Trusted Roots Certification Authorities".

Otherwise this error happens.